# Why is VS Code calling the wrong virtual environment as base?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, virtualenv, conda

I have some conda virtual environments in a server I SSH into in a daily basis. Logging in from the terminal and listing the environments gives me the following:

```
(base) [rgr6291@klc0201 ~]$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
fomc                     /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/fomc
r_conda                  /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/r_conda
rfe_paper                /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/rfe_paper
base                  *  /software/python-anaconda3/2019.10
```

So I have base and three virtual environments. I usually edit code on the server using Visual Studio Code and the Remote SSH extension. VS Code recognizes all these environments when I am prompted to select the Python interpreter:

[image]

It turns out that starting a terminal window *from* VS Code leads to different behavior whether I am on the `fomc` environment or not.

If I select, say, the `rfe_paper` environment and start a new terminal from withing VS Code, I get the following automatic output:

```
source activate rfe_paper
(base) [rgr6291@klc0201 HF_FOMC]$ source activate rfe_paper
(rfe_paper) [rgr6291@klc0201 HF_FOMC]$
```

It starts up the terminal and then activates the desired environment. However, the same procedure from the `fomc` environment leads to something different:

```
source /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/fomc/bin/activate
(base) [rgr6291@klc0201 HF_FOMC]$ source /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/fomc/bin/activate
(base) [rgr6291@klc0201 HF_FOMC]$ conda activate fomc

(base) [rgr6291@klc0201 HF_FOMC]$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/fomc
r_conda                  /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/r_conda
rfe_paper                /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/rfe_paper
```

Notice that there is an extra `source` call in the beginning. And somehow VS Code is misled and believes the `fomc` environment is the base one.

1. What might be causing this?
2. How to fix this?

It was working fine yesterday but it seems broken today. The only difference is that I exported the installed packages in `fomc` to an yml file this morning. I don't know how that would affect behavior.

By the way, let me report the following as well. This is the content of `~/.conda/envs/fomc/bin/activate`:

```
#!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="/home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/fomc"
# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
conda activate "$@"
```

I think CONDA_ROOT is wrong, but I have no idea of what it should actually be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is indeed odd. Any chance the `fomc` environment has the `conda` *package* installed? Usually only **base** should ever have it.

Comment: You are correct @merv. I have absolutely no idea on why it was installed but indeed it was. I should close this question I guess. Or delete it. I am not sure what is the correct procedure here.

Comment: I wrote up something to try if you wish. However, I will say that it's not clear to me that it is such a big problem. Other than the `conda env list` and some environment variables being out of whack, is there really any substantial impact on *functionality*?

Comment: @merv not really, no change in functionality. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ⚠️ **Caution:** *This is an untested recommendation. Please make sure the whole procedure is clear before attempting. Be sure to back up any files before changing them!*

I've not encountered this situation personally, but I suspect that resolving it will involve removing the `conda` package from the **fomc** environment. This may be sufficient; but it could also be important to ensure that the Conda initialization code in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is set up to use the actual **base** environment and not the scripts/entry points in the **fomc** environment.

So, I'd recommend first checking the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and make sure they don't have any paths referencing the **fomc**. If they do, then the entire initialization block, starting and ending with

```bash
# >>> conda initialize >>>
...
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

should be removed and then one should rerun the `conda init` command *with the real **base** environment active*, or using the full path to the **base** `conda`.

Once this is done, restart the shell and verify `conda` still works and points to the **base** (i.e., check `which conda`). Then attempt to remove the `conda` package from **fomc**, doing this *without* the **fomc** being active, i.e.,

```bash
conda remove -n fomc conda
```

That should be it.

Comment: Removing conda from ```fomc``` solved it!

Comment: Annoying bug with VS Code!